# Prime ng dropdown not showing list items on first click in edge browser, it just highlighting

Tags: angular, primeng

Find below is the screenshot for reference.
[image: prime ng dropdown along with bar chart]

**TS code for "Product Dropdown"**

```
products: ProductData[] = [
    { label: 'All Products' },
    { label: 'Combo', AppTypeId: 12 },
    { label: 'Dental', AppTypeId: 16 },
    { label: 'Vision', AppTypeId: 20 },
    { label: 'Association', AppTypeId: 3 },
    { label: 'Health Access', AppTypeId: 23 },
    { label: 'Secure Access', AppTypeId: 11 },
    { label: 'Premier Choice', AppTypeId: 17 },
    { label: 'Secure Advantage', AppTypeId: 13 },
    { label: 'Health Access Indemnity', AppTypeId: 24 },
    { label: 'Premier Advantage Indemnity', AppTypeId: 25 },
  ];
```

Html code for "Product dropdown"

```
 <div class="col-12 md:col-4 lg:col-4 xl:col-4">
      <p-dropdown [options]="products" optionLabel="label" placeholder="Select Product" styleClass="w-full"
        (onChange)="selectProduct($event)">
      </p-dropdown>
    </div>
```

prime ng dropdown should be show list of items on first click in any browser

Comment: Check if there are any console errors or warnings that may be causing the issue

Comment: Hey Raj, can you please supply the view code for the p-dropdown.  It sounds like the backend data was wiped-out.

Comment: Hey Phil, added code for the dropdown